# Problems with branches, messed up my master on a fork

Tags: git

I've gotten myself into a pickle with Git and I don't really know what I've done, or how to get back to where I expected to be.

I'll go through what I did and remember doing:

1. I [forked](https://github.com/xdaDaveShaw/FSharp.Charting) the F# Charting Repo and cloned it.
2. I made a branch `IsMarginVisibleSupport`
3. Made a single commit to the branch.
4. Pushed the changes to my remote.
5. Made a PR.
6. Don Syme merged it into the F# Charting Repo.
7. I deleted my branch on Git Hub.
8. Checked out `master` and did a `git up`.
9. Deleted the branch locally.

I thought all was good...

I then went to make another change

1. Created another branch, `IsMarginVisible-TestsAndComments`
2. Made 4 commits into it.

Things look OK on this branch.
I now *tried* to update my `master` with any changes that may have been made on the F# Charting remote. I'm not sure where or when in the process I did this and I'm not exactly sure what I did, I found stuff from various places but now I have a history that looks like this:

[image]

I have no idea what I've done...

Also at some point I have pushed my branch to GitHub: Also, I have [pushed](https://github.com/xdaDaveShaw/FSharp.Charting/commits/IsMarginVisible-TestsAndComments) my branch to GitHub.

All I wanted was any changes off Git Hub in my branch before I sent a PR up again.

Any ideas how I can make it look as it should please?

Comment: @AndrewC - updated question to mention I have pushed to GitHub

Comment: So you have origin/master and upstream/master.  I am guessing the 1 commit on origin/master is the same content as the commit with the same Subject on upstream/master?  If so, then you would want both your origin/master and your master pointing to upstream/master, then you would want to rebase IsMarginVisible-TestsAndComments against that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you commited to `master` by accident (“Uncomment IsMarginVisible”). Therefore you could not perform a fast forward to upstream/master and created a new merge commit, cluttering your commit history.

You should reset your master:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git reset --hard upstream/master` after verifying that you don't have any important uncommited changes. This will roll back any changes (commited and uncommited) to the state of `upstream/master`!
3. **Do not pull** at this point.
4. `git push --force origin master`

Your `master` now is in sync with the upstream master again and your fork/`origin` should have all the changes that were in the upstream `master`.

Remember, don't commit to `master` if you are working on forks for GitHub OSS projects, it makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

type `git reflog` on your local machine and you will see the whole history of what you have done so far.

From the graph that you showed here it look like your branch is not merged into master yet.

As long as you do not push no harm has been done, simply merge your local branches and verify the commit graph before you push.

Comment: Merge my branch into my master? With GitHub Flow I thought I sent a PR from my branch? Also, I have pushed my branch to GitHub: https://github.com/xdaDaveShaw/FSharp.Charting/commits/IsMarginVisible-TestsAndComments

Comment: if you are using PR so do it using PR, once clicking on the merge in the UI it will merge it. once you merge your branch master will have the code from both branches and all will be fine.